# Docker image remote Pycharm interpreter can't find shared object file

Tags: python-3.x, docker, pycharm

I'm using a docker image as a remote interpreter to test our application code. Upon running the test suite Python returns an error stating that it can't find a particular shared object file in the registered directory. The listed directory and error messages are below:

```
The registry is in directory
OnyxOsiris InprocServer32 = /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osl1/onyxosiris.so
```

However a couple of quick cd and ls commands within the container later, its clear that the file is in fact in the directory:

```
(base) root@4dc5e5ce2f65:/# cd /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osl1

(base) root@4dc5e5ce2f65:/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osl1# ls
__init__.py  __pycache__  _osl1.so  installcomponents.py  onyx.so  onyxosiris.so  osl1.py  osl1helperfuncs.py
```

I feel that I'm missing something important here but I can't tell what. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable. I had assumed that the folder containing the shared object files would be added to the path, as the same folder contained the executable. However, this is assumption was clearly wrong. Adding the path to this folder to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable within the docker container had the desired effect. Finally, creating a new image using the docker commit command resulted in a fully functional image that could be used effectively as a remote interpreter in the PyCharm project.